# Ubuntu freezes on the login screen after i close my laptop lid Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login, laptop, logout

I experience a Bug where the login screen doesn't work correctly after I closed the laptop lid. When i open it again the  login screen appears and I can move the cursor but I cannot click anything or enter something via the keyboard.
The only thing I can do is killing it and restart -> then everything works normally. The bug does not appear when I logout without closing the lid. But if I log out and close it afterwards the same problem appears.

I use a Sony Vaio with an Nvidia Geforce and an Intel i5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing proprietary drivers for your video card.

Goto **System Settings >> Software and Updates**

Click on **Additional Drivers** tab
Choose the Proprietary driver with Updates

Click on **Apply Changes**

Reboot, and try again.

Comment: Thx solved the problem